# Is there a significance to gold-colored loot chests in Captain Scarlett DLC?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've encountered a couple of gold-colored loot chests while completing quests in the Captain Scarlett DLC, and am wondering if they have any significance or it's just a glitch?

[image: Captain Scarlett Gold Loot Chest #1]
[image: Captain Scarlett Gold Loot Chest #2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its 100% a glitch. So doesnt matter which color they have.

Comment: Not only is it a glitch, but a cool one! :-) I've encountered monsters and containers of venomous green and scorching red, but never of such beautiful golden hue :-)